# Jaccard's distance matrix with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, distance

I would like to compute a distance matrix using the [Jaccard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) distance. And do so as fast as possible. I used to use [scikit-learn's pairwise_distances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html) function. But scikit-learn doesn't plan to support GPU, and there's even a [known bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8216) that makes the function slower when run in parallel.

My only constraint is that the resulting distance matrix can then be fed to [scikit-learn's DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) clustering algorithm. I was thinking about implementing the computation with tensorflow but couldn't find a nice and simple way to do it.

---

PS: I have reasons to precompute the distance matrix instead of letting DBSCAN do it as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Hej I was facing the same problem.

Given the idea that the jaccard similarity is the ratio of true postives (tp) to the sum of true positives, false negatives (fn) and false positives (fp), I came up with this solution:

```
    def jaccard_distance(self):
        tp = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(self.target, self.prediction), 1)
        fn = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(self.target, 1-self.prediction), 1)
        fp = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(1-self.target, self.prediction), 1)
        return 1 - (tp / (tp + fn + fp))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You have 3 matrix multiplications, that might be bad for performance.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a tensorflow expert, but here is the solution I got. As far as I know, the only ways in tensorflow to do a computation on *all-pairs* of a list is to do a matrix multiplication or use the broadcasting rules, this solution uses both at some point.

So let's assume we have an input boolean matrix of `n_samples` rows, one per set, and `n_features` columns, one per possible element. A value `True` in the *i*-th row, *j*-th column means the *i*-th set contains the element *j*. Just like [scikit-learn's pairwise_distances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html) expect. We can then proceed as follow.

1. Cast the matrix to numbers, getting 1 for `True` and 0 for `False`.
2. Multiply the matrix by its own transpose. This produce a matrix where each element `M[i][j]` contains size of the intersection between the *i*-th and *j*-th sets.
3. Compute a `cardv` vector that contains the cardinality of all the sets by summing the input matrix by rows.
4. Make a row and a column vector from `cardv`.
5. Compute `1 - M / (cardvrow + cardvcol - M)`. The broadcasting rules will do all the work when adding a row and a column vector.

This algorithm as a whole seems a bit hack-ish, but it works and produce results within a reasonable margin from the result computed by scikit-learn's `pairwise_distances` function. A better algorithm should probably make a single pass on every pair of input vectors and compute only half of the matrix as it is symmetric. Any improvement is welcome.

```
setsin = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=(N, M))
sets = tf.cast(setsin, tf.float16)
mat = tf.matmul(sets, sets, transpose_b=True, name="Main_matmul")
#mat = tf.cast(mat, tf.float32, name="Upgrade_mat")
#sets = tf.cast(sets, tf.float32, name="Upgrade_sets")
cardinal = tf.reduce_sum(sets, 1, name="Richelieu")
cardinalrow = tf.expand_dims(cardinal, 0)
cardinalcol = tf.expand_dims(cardinal, 1)

mat = 1 - mat / (cardinalrow + cardinalcol - mat)
```

I used `float16` type as it seems much faster than `float32`. Casting to `float32` might only be useful if the cardinals are large enough to make them inaccurate or if more precision is needed when performing the division. But even when the casts are needed, it seems to be still relevant to do the matrix multiplication as `float16`.