# Pytorch: How to compute IoU (Jaccard Index) for semantic segmentation

Tags: pytorch

Can someone provide a toy example of how to compute IoU (intersection over union) for semantic segmentation in pytorch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261072/jaccards-distance-matrix-with-tensorflow shows how to implement it in tensorflow. Porting that to PyTorch should be easily possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this somewhere and adapted it for me. I'll post the link if I can find it again. Sorry in case this was a dublicate.
The key function here is the function called `iou`. The wrapping function `evaluate_performance` is not universal, but it shows that one needs to iterate over all results before computing `IoU`.

```
import torch 
import pandas as pd  # For filelist reading
import myPytorchDatasetClass  # Custom dataset class, inherited from torch.utils.data.dataset


def iou(pred, target, n_classes = 12):
  ious = []
  pred = pred.view(-1)
  target = target.view(-1)

  # Ignore IoU for background class ("0")
  for cls in xrange(1, n_classes):  # This goes from 1:n_classes-1 -> class "0" is ignored
    pred_inds = pred == cls
    target_inds = target == cls
    intersection = (pred_inds[target_inds]).long().sum().data.cpu()[0]  # Cast to long to prevent overflows
    union = pred_inds.long().sum().data.cpu()[0] + target_inds.long().sum().data.cpu()[0] - intersection
    if union == 0:
      ious.append(float('nan'))  # If there is no ground truth, do not include in evaluation
    else:
      ious.append(float(intersection) / float(max(union, 1)))
  return np.array(ious)


def evaluate_performance(net):
    # Dataloader for test data
    batch_size = 1  
    filelist_name_test = '/path/to/my/test/filelist.txt'
    data_root_test = '/path/to/my/data/'
    dset_test = myPytorchDatasetClass.CustomDataset(filelist_name_test, data_root_test)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=dset_test,  
                                              batch_size=batch_size,
                                              shuffle=False,
                                              pin_memory=True)
    data_info = pd.read_csv(filelist_name_test, header=None)
    num_test_files = data_info.shape[0]  
    sample_size = num_test_files

    # Containers for results
    preds = Variable(torch.zeros((sample_size, 60, 36, 60)))
    gts = Variable(torch.zeros((sample_size, 60, 36, 60)))

    dataiter = iter(test_loader) 
    for i in xrange(sample_size):
        images, labels, filename = dataiter.next()
        images = Variable(images).cuda()
        labels = Variable(labels)
        gts[i:i+batch_size, :, :, :] = labels
        outputs = net(images)
        outputs = outputs.permute(0, 2, 3, 4, 1).contiguous()
        val, pred = torch.max(outputs, 4)
        preds[i:i+batch_size, :, :, :] = pred.cpu()
    acc = iou(preds, gts)
    return acc
```

Answer (score 22):

As of 2021, there's no need to implement your own IoU, as `torchmetrics` comes equipped with it - [here's the link](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/jaccard_index.html).
It is named `torchmetrics.JaccardIndex` (previously `torchmetrics.IoU`) and calculates what you want.
It works with PyTorch and PyTorch Lightning, also with distributed training.

From the documentation:

> `torchmetrics.JaccardIndex(num_classes, ignore_index=None, absent_score=0.0, threshold=0.5, multilabel=False, reduction='elementwise_mean', compute_on_step=None, **kwargs)`
>
> Computes Intersection over union, or Jaccard index calculation:
>
> J(A,B) = \frac{|A\cap B|}{|A\cup B|}
>
> Where: `A` and `B` are both tensors of the same size, containing integer class values. They may be subject to conversion from input data (see description below). Note that it is different from box IoU.
>
> Works with binary, multiclass and multi-label data. Accepts probabilities from a model output or integer class values in  prediction. Works with multi-dimensional preds and target.
>
> Forward accepts
>
> - `preds` (float or long tensor): `(N, ...)` or `(N, C, ...)` where C is the number of classes
> - `target` (long tensor): `(N, ...)` If preds and target
>   are the same shape and preds is a float tensor, we use the
>   `self.threshold` argument to convert into integer labels. This is the case for binary and multi-label probabilities.
>
> If preds has an extra dimension as in the case of multi-class scores we perform an argmax on `dim=1`.

Official example:

```py
from torchmetrics import JaccardIndex
target = torch.randint(0, 2, (10, 25, 25))
pred = torch.tensor(target)
pred[2:5, 7:13, 9:15] = 1 - pred[2:5, 7:13, 9:15]
jaccard = JaccardIndex(task='multiclass', num_classes=2)
jaccard(pred, target)
```

Returns `tensor(0.9660)`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as using tested implementation is much cleaner and safe than custom implementations.

Comment: see [JaccardIndex](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/modules.html?highlight=IoU#jaccardindex)

Comment: @dominik-filipiak, can you update the link in your answer to the updated one, as provided by irudyak

Comment: @SauravMaheshkar thanks for the remarks, I updated the link.

Answer (score 6):

Say your outputs are of shape `[32, 256, 256]` # 32 is the minibatch size and 256x256 is the image's height and width, and the labels are also the same shape.

Then you can use sklearn's `jaccard_similarity_score` after some reshaping.

If both are torch tensors, then:

```
lbl = labels.cpu().numpy().reshape(-1)
target = output.cpu().numpy().reshape(-1)
```

Now:

```
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score as jsc
print(jsc(target,lbl))
```

Comment: In the latest Sklearn, like 0.24.1, the function name has been changed to jaccard_score. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#jaccard-similarity-score