# How to test IOU score after training a YOLO model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, yolov8

The Yolov8 model is now trained with custom data and i am able to run prediction over some images for example like this

```
!yolo predict model=/content/runs/detect/train/weights/best.pt source=dataset/images/test/004250005.jpg
```

so i get a image stored now i want to calculate IOU score from the given data my model is stored in that path (best.pt) and the output is stored in the following location

```
/content/runs/detect/predict4/004250005.jpg
```

How do i calculate it ? I am using Pytorch

Comment: Did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260415/pytorch-how-to-compute-iou-jaccard-index-for-semantic-segmentation

Comment: @DSarkar yes i did but there is no place i have seen him do the analysis on the model  which was made